# UITextView Not Opening URL When Clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` that has an attributed string inside, which contains a URL. The attributed string is being converted to a link, but when you press the link you get an error:

> Unknown DDResult category 1 for result ; could not find any actions for URL www.myurl.com

Here is my code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"My Text", nil)];
NSRange range = [str.mutableString rangeOfString:@"www.myurl.com" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    [str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"CourierPrime-Bold" size:15] range:NSMakeRange(0, range.location)];
    [str addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.myurl.com"] range:range];
    [str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor brownColor] range:range];
}


self.welcomeText.editable = NO; 
self.welcomeText.attributedText = str;

//As a note, I have tried this with the value 0 and UIDataDetectorTypeLink
//and neither option worked.
self.welcomeText.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

I am using an `XIB` and in the behavior options I have `selectable` enabled, and in the detection options I have `links` selected.

I would like for the link to be opened in the phones mobile browser if possible, rather than creating a webview.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The URL needs a scheme.

This:

```
[str addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.myurl.com"] range:range];
```

needs to be:

```
[str addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myurl.com"] range:range];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly.

Comment: This won't work for the scenario where the Link Attribute is automatically detected by the UITextView, and the input is user based.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen But that isn't what the question was asking. The answer is correct for the original question. If you have a different situation not covered here, post your own question with your own specific details. No need to down vote an answer that was never meant to address your own specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift** :

The URL needs to be **Secure** (https)

IOS doesn't allow you to redirect the user to non secure links , so provide links with **https**

and to make a specific string clickable in `UITextView` using **Swift**

you can do as follow :

```
let link = "https://www.google.com"
let range = (text as NSString).range(of: link)
attribute.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.link: link], range: range)
```